# Scanner object has a class attribute instead of in code initialisation

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, java.util.scanner

Today, I have encounter a problem with `Scanner` object while programming a server/client application. I have solved the problem but I don't understand why my solution solved the problem.

At first, in my application I had some memory leak warning when compiling the project (JAVA 8, eclipse) 
 because I was using `Scanner` to ask input from the user but didn't close it. When I try to close the scanner my other class where throwing exception like `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. I learned that I had a similar problem to : [Cannot use multiple Scanner objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053580/cannot-use-multiple-scanner-objects-in-java) but between classes. When I was closing a scanner in a class the other class (thread) scanner couldn't execute.  (java.util.NoSuchElementException)

The solution I found to solve this problem was to put a Scanner function as a class function member:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {

    private Scanner scanner;

   /*some code*/

}
```

When doing so I lost my memory leak warning.

Why having the scanner as a class member solved the warning ? Is it because of the class destructor ?

Comment: what was your original scope? its not clear

Comment: I think my question is not necessary related to the scope of the variable. I'll try to put it in other words. I don't understand how having a scanner as a local variable in a function can cause memory leak without closing but not a scanner has a class member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you create a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), you need to [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--) it once you no longer need it.

The `Scanner` class has several, overloaded constructors where each one takes a different type of argument. There is a constructor that takes a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) argument. There is a constructor that takes a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) argument. And there is a constructor that takes a [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) argument. In order for your Java program to accept input from the user, via the computer keyboard, you use the constructor that takes an `InputStream` like so:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This is because the static member [`in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) of class `java.lang.System` has type `InputStream`. You should think of `System.in` as encapsulating the keyboard on your computer. If you close `System.in`, it's like closing your keyboard and that is something you shouldn't do.

Now the [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) IDE is not smart enough to realize that your code is creating a `Scanner` that essentially encapsulates the computer keyboard (and therefore should not be closed). *Eclipse* only knows that any `Scanner` that you create should eventually be closed and since your code does not close the `Scanner` you created, *Eclipse* displays a warning that you haven't closed a `Scanner` that you created. In the displayed warning you are offered three suggestions on how to get rid of the warning. The first two refer to an annotation that you can add, namely

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
```

The third suggestion requires you to change the *Eclipse* configuration. You do this by selecting the *Preferences* item of the *Window* menu that appears at the top of the *Eclipse* IDE. In the *Preferenes* window, select Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings and change the *Resource leak* setting to Ignore as shown in the following screen capture:

[image: Eclipse preferences window]

Note however, that this configuration setting applies to **all** resources, not just `Scanner`, so if you open a regular file in your java code and don't close it, *Eclipse* will not warn you.

Personally, I simply ignore the warning since I know that I should not close a `Scanner` created with `System.in` or I add an annotation.

Comment: Why not just arrange your code so you create one System.in Scanner, and close it at the end of your application?

Comment: Yes, this is an option but I want to know why putting the Scanner has a class member remove the warning indicating that the Scanner is not close.
In my first program version Scanner was a local variable asking for some information in a function
void function() {
Scanner scanner = new scanner // Warning here
/* scanner stuff*/
}
The problem with that I couldn't close the scanner because I had other Scanner variable using System.in like Abra explained. But when I put Scanner as a class member no more memory leak warning. How putting a scanner variable has a class member avoid memory leak

Answer (score 0):

Although Java usually auto-release the memory when you leave the scope some classes require special treatment.

Generally these are classes who has something to do with files and connections (to db or just sockets). 
The latter is required  because the underlying OS requires those resource to be explicitly released (in general).

In the Java 8 there was introduced [Autoclosable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) and it solves some of the problems but ultimately you need to be careful.

Here is an example for Scanner with autoclosable:

```
File file = new File("filename here");
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
    // do something here, note you dont need close as it is autoclosable
}
```