# Solved!: the for loop in my code won't repeatedly repeat, gather input, and put it into an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input, java.util.scanner

I am suppose to ask the user for how many integers they want to enter, and then use a loop to create a prompt message for each integer, so that the numbers can be entered. Each integer that is entered is stored in an array.

However, every time I run the code, an error appears. The code doesn't repeat during the loop, and it looks like this:

> Please enter the number of values you would like to enter:
>
> > 1

> Please enter for index value of 0:
>
> > -Error-

I can't figure out why the loop and array aren't working, thank you!

````
     ```public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create and label variables
    int intCount, n, x;
    
    //create a scanner that will accept the user's input and figure out how many 
    numbers the user wants to enter
    Scanner Inputnumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of values you would like to 
    enter:");
    n = Inputnumber.nextInt();
    Inputnumber.close();
    
    //create a integer array to store the numbers
    int [] integers;
    integers = new int [n];
    
    //create a while loop to continuously ask the user for what numbers they 
    want to enter
    for (intCount = 0; intCount < n; intCount++){
        Scanner InputInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter for index value of "+intCount+": ");
        x = InputInt.nextInt();
        integers [intCount] = x;
        InputInt.close();
    }```
````

Comment: You should not close your scanners.

Comment: Please mention the error you are facing too!! @Liam

Comment: I cleaned up some of the grammar and formatted the session info, but you may need to provide some more details about the exact error message, or work on creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just edit your question directly to improve it if there is more info people may need to reproduce or understand the specific problem you are seeing.

Comment: Don't close what you didn't open! You are closing the scanner, which closes the underlying inputstream – which is `System.in`. By closing it, you won't be able to read from it again!

Comment: By the way, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase, class names in PascalCase.

Comment: @VijayD I don't know what kind of error it is. I just started learning java last week.

Comment: The problem was solved, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053580/cannot-use-multiple-scanner-objects-in-java)

You don't need to use two separate Scanner Objects.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create and label variables
        int intCount, n, x;

        // create a scanner that will accept the user's input and figure out how many
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of values you would like to enter:");
        n = input.nextInt();
        

        // create a integer array to store the numbers
        int[] integers;
        integers = new int[n];

        // create a while loop to continuously ask the user for what numbers they

        for (intCount = 0; intCount < n; intCount++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter for index value of " + intCount + ": ");
            x = input.nextInt();
            integers[intCount] = x;
            
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```